# Lorem shortcut on Visual Studio 2013 not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, lorem-ipsum

I saw some people on internet saying that if you type "lorem" in the view of ASP.NET, and then hit TAB, then it will be generated a "Lorem Ipsum" with 30 words.

I think its great, but I can't make it happen! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) installed. [Download link](http://vswebessentials.com/)

I have it installed, but didn't know about that feature so thanks for highlighting it!

Comment: oh yea! That's it! By the way, you can also type "lorem10", so only 10 words will be generated. You can also type lorem5, lorem6... =).

Comment: Struggle to get it working initially. It does not work inside a HTML tag but works fine outside?

Comment: @alansiqueira27 Command `lorem10` also works very well in VSCode, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install Dummy Text Generator from marketplace for lorem ipsum and other text generators

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DummyTextGenerator

I know this is annoying to install new extension for every other feature.